# Designing a database for categories and subcategories

Tags: database, database-design

Basically I'm trying to figure out how Amazon architected their book section. Check out Amazon's book page here (https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_2_ex_n_1?rh=n%3A283155&bbn=283155&ie=UTF8&qid=1522817105).

We are given several main categories: Arts & Photography, Biographies & Memoirs, etc.

If I click on Biographies & Memoirs for example, I'm lead to a series of sub categories. I.E. Biographies & Memoirs > Historical > Asia > Japan

There are repeating sub-category names for example: History > Asia > Japan

How can I map this kind of information so that it is scalable?

Below is the wrong way to do it...?

```
Categories table
+----+-----------------------+-----------+
| id |         name          | parent_id |
+----+-----------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Biographies & Memoirs | null      |
|  2 | Historical            | 1         |
|  3 | Asia                  | 2         |
|  4 | History               | null      |
|  5 | Asia                  | 4         |
|  6 | Japan                 | 5         |
|  7 | Japan                 | 3         |
+----+-----------------------+-----------+

Books
+----+-------------------------------------+----------+
| id |                name                 | category |
+----+-------------------------------------+----------+
|  1 | The Lone Samurai                    |        7 |
|  2 | The Human Tradition in Modern Japan |        7 |
|  3 | Okinawa: The Last Battle            |        6 |
+----+-------------------------------------+----------+

Authors
+----+---------------+----------+
| id |   firstname   | lastname |
+----+---------------+----------+
|  1 | James M.      | Burns    |
|  2 | Roy E.        | Appleman |
|  3 | Russell A.    | Gugeler  |
|  4 | John          | Stevens  |
|  5 | William Scott | Wilson   |
|  6 | Anne          | Walthall |
+----+---------------+----------+

Authors to books (Many to many)
+---------+-----------+
| book_id | author_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       3 |         1 |
|       3 |         2 |
|       3 |         3 |
|       3 |         4 |
|       1 |         5 |
|       2 |         6 |
+---------+-----------+
```